# Can we conclude that there is food and drink in heaven because Jesus ate and drank after the resurrection?

Tags: eschatology, resurrection-body, new-earth

The *glorified body* of Jesus who appeared to the disciples after resurrection is one of the most foundational truths of Christianity, the basis of our hope for our future resurrection of the body as well.

**My question**: since in his glorified body Jesus ate and drank with his disciples before his Ascension ([Lk 24:42-43,John 21:12-14,Acts 10:41-43](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lk+24%3A42-43%2Cjohn+21%3A12-14%2CActs+10%3A41-43&version=NLT)), can we conclude that there is eating and drinking in the new heaven and new earth since we will have similar glorified body that Jesus has, and which was shown to be capable of eating and drinking?

Or should we interpret the verses as "accommodation" only, so that Jesus can prove to the disciples that he is REAL and/or that the resurrection is BODILY (not just spirit)?  Or maybe we should interpret the eating and drinking not literally, but find the theological message behind them?

#### Food for thoughts

1. For an argument that Luke didn't intend the eating and drinking to be read literally, read the 1988 *Gregorianum* journal article [Did Jesus Eat the Fish (Luke 24:42-43)?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23577821) by Jesuit scholar [Gerald O'Collins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_O%27Collins).
2. If there IS eating and drinking in the new creation, how about the final product of our glorified digestive system? Pardon the image, but are there toilets in heaven?  How about the [39 trillion microbes that we carry in our human microbiome](https://www.sciencefocus.com/the-human-body/human-microbiome/), are they glorified as well?
3. If there is NO eating and drinking in the new creation, how should we understand the references to the

   - **Great Banquet** ("eat at the feast" *cf*. Luke 14:18-24, "eat and drink at my table" *cf*. Luke 22:29-30), and the
   - **Marriage Supper of the Lamb** ("until that day when I drink it anew with you" *cf*. Matt 26:29, "I will not drink again of the fruit of the vine until the kingdom of God comes" *cf*. Luke 22:16, "Blessed are those who are invited to the wedding supper of the Lamb!" *cf*. Rev 19:6-9)?

Comment: **Note**: if denominational scoping is necessary, please comment and I'll modify the question.

Comment: Religious leader David O. McKay is reported to have said *if there aren't chocolate brownies in heaven, I don't want to go* =)

Comment: @HoldToTheRod  For me, a glorified plant-based steak would be nice (no cows are hurt in the meal preparation :-) )

Comment: @GratefulDisciple. How about lab grown meat?  Yummy sounding ain’t it?

Comment: @User14 Interesting possibility.  I honestly wonder how scientists would feel if there are no labs in the new earth; they must feel deprived.  As a software developer and a pianist, I want to imagine there are STILL computers and musical instruments !

Comment: @GratefulDisciple. Yeah I always challenge folks who say new earth means going back to horse and wagon days.

Answer (score 3):

At the last supper Jesus said:

> But I say unto you, I will not drink henceforth of this fruit of the vine, until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father’s kingdom. (Matt. 26:29)

The plainest rendering of this passage indicates there will be eating/drinking in heaven. In mortality, food & drink are necessary for survival. In the resurrection, the incorruptible bodies Paul speaks of (e.g. 1 Cor. 15:53) apparently will not die for lack of food.

This suggests, at least tentatively, that consumption of food & beverage in heaven will be available, but not necessary.

Regrettably, neither does Paul tell us anything about the Celestial digestive system, nor does John report on the sewage system in the new heaven & new earth.